# SQL query to find the changes in status throughout the day

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I have a database table named `STATUS_HISTORY`

1. ID- ID of the record ( Combination of ID and REV is unique)
2. REV - Revision id, if any record get changed a new entry is created with incremented revision id
3. STATUS - It can contain three value

   - OPEN
   - CLOSE
   - INPROGRESS
4. UPDATED_BY_ID - ID of the user who has
           updated the record
5. UPDATED_TIMESTAMP -  when was this record updated.
6. TASK_ID - the task for which status is changing

Now in  whole day a record can move to different statuses.

I am looking for a query to give a response like below:

```
╔═════════════════╤══════╤════════════╤═══════╗
║ Hour_of_the_day │ OPEN │ INPROGRESS │ CLOSE ║
╠═════════════════╪══════╪════════════╪═══════╣
║ 1               │ 10   │ 0          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 2               │ 10   │ 0          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 3               │ 10   │ 0          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 4               │ 9    │ 1          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 5               │ 9    │ 1          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 6               │ 8    │ 2          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 7               │ 8    │ 2          │ 0     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 8               │ 8    │ 1          │ 1     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 9               │ 8    │ 0          │ 2     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 10              │ 6    │ 2          │ 2     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 11              │ 6    │ 1          │ 3     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 12              │ 5    │ 2          │ 3     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 13              │ 4    │ 3          │ 3     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 14              │ 4    │ 3          │ 3     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 15              │ 2    │ 3          │ 5     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 16              │ 1    │ 2          │ 7     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 17              │ 0    │ 1          │ 9     ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 18              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 19              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 20              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 21              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 22              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 23              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╟─────────────────┼──────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 24              │ 0    │ 0          │ 10    ║
╚═════════════════╧══════╧════════════╧═══════╝
```

**Note**: Suppose a task has been marked as OPEN and there is no change in the status from last 5 hours it has to be counted for all the 5 hours. same goes with other status like close and inprogress because not all the entries will change every hour.

Basically at each hour how many tickets were open, closed or in progress.

I am not sure how to write a query for this logic. but below is my try which is given totally different output.

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP , 'HH24') AS hour,
         COUNT(*) AS numPerHour, t.STATUS
    FROM STATUS_HISTORY t
    WHERE t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP  >= to_date('29-OCT-18','DD-MON-YY')
    AND t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP     < to_date('30-OCT-18','DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP , 'HH24'), t.STATUS;

╔═════════════════╤════════════╤════════════╗
║ Hour_of_the_day │ NumPerHour │ INPROGRESS ║
╠═════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╣
║ 06              │ 2          │ OPEN       ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 09              │ 5          │ OPEN       ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 09              │ 2          │ OPEN       ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 09              │ 3          │ CLOSE      ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 07              │ 1          │ INPROGRESS ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 08              │ 8          │ OPEN       ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 11              │ 1          │ CLOSE      ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 08              │ 1          │ INPROGRESS ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 07              │ 3          │ OPEN       ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 11              │ 2          │ CLOSE      ║
╟─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────╢
║ 12              │ 1          │ INPROGRESS ║
╚═════════════════╧════════════╧════════════╝
```

I would like to understand if there is another way to handle it via java program may be or the query can provide this results.

Comment: When does a closed task cease to be of interest? What if there is no activity at all for a task on this day - is there an open task for some time in the past? Is status_history a large table, can you afford to lock or are you happy to have approximate numbers (the consequence of not locking it) while your query runsu).Do you intend to run this query during the day or at day end or some other freqency?

Comment: TASK_ID has tasks for all the tasks for a day, so initially all the tasks are open at the start of the day. its not a very big table.

Comment: You don't open tasks during the day?

Comment: no we don't open it daily.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
select COUNT( CASE WHEN STATUS = 'OPEN' THEN 1 END ) as OPEN,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INPROGRESS' THEN 1 END ) as INPROGRESS,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CLOSE' THEN 1 END ) as CLOSE
      ....
      ....
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP , 'HH24') --remove t.STATUS
```

Comment: This gives the results only in which hour there is a change. But suppose there is no change we would like to have same status as the previous hour. e.g. at hour 1 the status is 1 - open , 1 - close , 0 - inprogress . now there is no change in hour 2 still the status remains same. but its not available via the query you have mentioned.

Comment: @Ashu : Edit your question and add sample rows for `STATUS_HISTORY` to get exactly the result you are expecting. A [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) simulation will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a CASE:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP , 'HH24') AS hour,
         COUNT(*) AS numPerHour, sum(case when t.STATUS='OPEN' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPEN,
         sum(case when t.STATUS='CLOSE' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CLOSE,
         sum(case when t.STATUS='INPROGRESS' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INPROGRESS

    FROM STATUS_HISTORY t
    WHERE t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP  >= to_date('29-OCT-18','DD-MON-YY')
    AND t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP     < to_date('30-OCT-18','DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP , 'HH24'), t.STATUS
```